# How do I get the bits from a byte in golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to compute the Hamming distance between two byte's, such that

`HammingDist(byte(255), byte(0)) == 8`

I need the bits in each byte, but I can't find any function in any of the built-in packages for doing so. So, given `byte(1)` how do I get the bit representation 00000001?

Comment: You can use BitReader as in https://play.golang.org/p/Wyr_K9YAro

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can see the visual representation of bits using `fmt.Sprintf("%08b", ...)` as others have already suggested.

However, if you want to use the bits in operations, such as for calculating the Hamming distance, you'll need to use [bitwise operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators).

To calculate the n<sup>th</sup> bit of a byte, you'll need to `bitwise AND` that byte with another byte whose n<sup>th</sup> bit is set to 1 and the rest to 0 (aka masking). In other words, that other byte (mask) is the number 2<sup>n-1</sup>.

For example, to find the 1st bit of the number 13 (00001101), we would have to mask it with 2<sup>0</sup> = 1 (00000001). We compare the output of performing bitwise AND on both numbers to the mask. If they are equal, it means that the nth bit is 1, otherwise it is 0. We continue like this and find all the bits. Illustrated in Go code:

```
fmt.Print(13 & 1) // Output: 1 -> 1
fmt.Print(13 & 2) // Output: 0 -> 0
fmt.Print(13 & 4) // Output: 4 -> 1
fmt.Print(13 & 8) // Output: 8 -> 1
// Not necessary to continue, but shown for the sake of the example
fmt.Print(13 & 16) // Output: 0 -> 0
fmt.Print(13 & 32) // Output: 0 -> 0
fmt.Print(13 & 64) // Output: 0 -> 0
fmt.Print(13 & 128) // Output: 0 -> 0
```

Therefore, 13 in binary is 00001101.

Here's a function I wrote recently for calculating the Hamming distance between two arrays of bytes. Just pass an array consisting of a single byte each in your case

```
func hamming(a, b []byte) (int, error) {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return 0, errors.New("a b are not the same length")
    }

    diff := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        b1 := a[i]
        b2 := b[i]
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            mask := byte(1 << uint(j))
            if (b1 & mask) != (b2 & mask) {
                diff++
            }
        }
    }
    return diff, nil
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/O1EGdzDYAn

Comment: out of curiousity, do you know why `%b` alone only shows 6 bits?

Answer (score 7):

fmt.Sprintf("%08b", byte(1)) is great idea. It shows you, how the number is store internally. And example to compute hamming distance (very boring) could be:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func HamDist(n1,n2 uint8) uint8 {
    var w uint8 = 0
    if n1&1 != n2&1 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&2 != n2&2 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&4 != n2&4 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&8 != n2&8 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&16 != n2&16 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&32 != n2&32 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&64 != n2&64 {
        w++
    }
    if n1&128 != n2&128 {
        w++
    }
    return w
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(HamDist(255,0))
}
```

And now tasks for you:

1. rewrite the code using a loop
2. extend program to compute hamming distance of 16-bit number
3. please think what xor operator does and whether should not be possible compute HammingDistance easier, if you has defined a function that computes Hamming weight.

Comment: Very nice answer, educating instead of giving away the straight solution. Keep it up!

Answer (score 5):

```
import "math/bits"

bits.OnesCount8(byte(0) ^ byte(255))
```

Comment: This gives me a huge performance gain. Thanks. (10 fold to be precise)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
fmt.Printf("%08b", YourNumber)
```

You can also use `%016b` or `%032b` or any other.

Answer (score 0):

There's been some great answers here, but another way to calculate the Hamming distance between two bytes is to XOR them and count the number of 1s (the weight). The easiest way to count the 1s that I know of is to get the last bit, by masking it with a 1, and then shift right.

Here's a function I wrote in golang to calculate the Hamming distance between two strings.

```
func HammingDistance(s1, s2 string) (int, error) {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Hamming distance of strings of different lengths %d and %d", len(s1), len(s2))
    }
    b1 := []byte(s1)
    b2 := []byte(s2)
    distance := 0
    for i := range b1 {
        xored := b1[i] ^ b2[i]
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            distance += int(xored & 1)
            xored = xored >> 1
        }
    }
    return distance, nil
}
```

To calculate the Hamming distance of two bytes, you would only need the inner for loop.